# Finding deleted threads

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Is it possible to restore deleted threads? I didn't know admins delete them. If I did I would have saved them; there were some interesting discussions. I really need them.

Comment: What do you mean by deleted threads? Comments , which is its most common meaning or actual questions?

Comment: @Mari-Lou, I meant my questions :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still read deleted posts if you have posted them and have a link to them (either via the 'Recently deleted questions' at the bottom of [your profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions) – that link will soon show [*all* your deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/295232)).

Moderators do delete posts now and then, but for example [this recent question of yours](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301307/a-common-situation-the-bedside-table) was [deleted automatically](/help/roomba) because the system deemed it not worth keeping (it was closed and had a negative score).

Comment: Do they delete them completely or are they just hidden? I remeber there were about 20 pages not just 12. Now it shows only 12 pages of my questions.

Comment: Deleted comment. I misread.

Comment: @AntoniaA they're just hidden. Outright deletion is reserved for rare instances of blatant abuse, e.g. child porn.

Comment: @Glorfindel, could you tell me how to find them?  I definitely didn't abuse any forum rules.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, they were important grammar questions :(

Comment: @AntoniaA no, you certainly didn't. I see there are 38 deleted questions. You can find the most recent ones via your profile, and soon (next month) you'll be able to see them all. If there's particular one you need sooner, you'll need to tell me some details about it so I can find it.

Comment: @Glorfindel I didn't know I would be able to see them again.   I wish I could see the whole list of my 38 questions to re-read them and print. I really need tense-related questions. Could you find tense-related ones? But why do admins hide them? You said I would be able to see them again.

Comment: @AntoniaA you will be able to see them in a month. *We* don't hide them, the system does ... on some larger sites like [so] this is necessary to weed out the really bad questions. English Language Learners uses the same system, there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I see. Thank you!